# IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface not working on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My main question is, how can I reverse engineer a private API function that already exists, but has been modified in a new version of iOS?

I have created an iOS application to record the screen content using IOSurface and IOMobileFramebuffer. The main functions the framebuffer use to open it are `IOMobileFramebufferGetMainDisplay(connect)` and `IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface`.

These functions have been used since the very first version of the app, and they have worked on all versions of iOS 7 and 8. However, on the latest iOS 9 beta, which is beta 5, the function `IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface` does not work. The function does not return 0, as it should when it successfully opens the framebuffer.

This other user on StackOverflow seems to also be experiencing the same issue: [IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface function failed on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136308/iomobileframebuffergetlayerdefaultsurface-function-failed-on-ios-9). We have a reference to IOMobileFramebufferConnection named “_framebufferConnection” and an IOSurfaceRef named “_screenSurface” Here is the current code:

`IOMobileFramebufferGetMainDisplay(&_framebufferConnection);
IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface(_framebufferConnection, 0, &_screenSurface;`

As stated before, these work perfectly on iOS 7-8, but on iOS 9, the second function crashes. I have also looked at the binaries with the symbols for both versions and compared them. The second parameter of the LDR is slightly different in iOS 9, when compared to the iOS 8.4.1 binary. So, back to the main question, how can I reverse engineer `IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface`, or see how in what way it’s actually been modified on iOS 9?

Comment: what ios9 version are you using?

Comment: iOS 9 beta 5. But the same occurs on all iOS 9 betas/versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe @nevyn is correct. However, I would like to elaborate a bit more. I have looked into this exact issue extensively, and the `IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface` function *does* return -536870201, while it should return 0 if it runs the function without any problems. This error is on the internet, but it only appears when users encounter generic problems with QuickTime. It could be that Apple has indeed locked up the framework completely, and needs an Apple-only entitlement to access the framebuffer. We cannot add these entitlements, since it also has to be on the provisioning profile. I currently am trying to read and interpret the disassembly and doing some reverse engineering work on the IOMobileFramebuffer binary to see if any of the parameters have changed since the last iOS version. I will surely update this answer if I discover anything. But if this is the case, I would suggest trying to find another method of trying to capture/record the screen content.

**-UPDATE-**

It seems as if there is evidence that this would be the case, if you read [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-kernel/2006/Sep/msg00049.html), it shows the exact same error code, and it means that the function is "unsupported", and returns an IOKit error. At least we know what this means now. However, I am still unsure of how to fix it, or to make the function work. I will continue looking into this.

**UPDATE 2**

I have actually discovered a brand new class in iOS 9, "FigScreenCaptureController", and it is part of the MediaToolbox framework! What the strange thing is though, is why would Apple include this only in iOS 9? So, maybe there will be a way to record the display through [this](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/FigScreenCaptureController.h)...I will be looking into this class more in depth very soon.

Comment: hey @anthonya1999, any luck using FigScreenCaptureController to capture the screen?

Comment: @ShirishKamath I know this is a late reply, but I have looked around in the class a bit, and you can call start/stop capture just fine, but I don't know how to set it up. (ie. video path, framerate, etc.) I will continue to see what I can do with this...

Answer (score 10):

To answer the question of "how in what way it’s actually been modified on iOS 9", I did some digging into `IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface` on iOS8 vs iOS9 (GM). Here are the results of what I found:

**Setup:**

`IOMobileFramebufferRef fb;
IOMobileFramebufferGetMainDisplay(&fb);`

**iOS8 Implementation:**

- Calls through to `kern_GetLayerDefaultSurface`
- Which accesses underlying IOConnection

  `io_connect_t fbConnect = *(io_connect_t *)((char *)fb + 20)`
- To retrieve the IOSurfaceID via

  `IOSurfaceID surfaceID;
  uint32_t outCount = 1;
  IOConnectCallScalarMethod(fbConnect, 3, {0, 0}, 2, &surfaceID, &outCount)`
- Returns `IOSurfaceLookup(surfaceID)`

**iOS9 Implementation:**

- Same steps as above aside from the return
- *Then* tries to retrieve a mach port to access the surface via

  `io_service_t fbService = *(io_service_t *)((char *)fb + 16)
  mach_port_t surfacePort;
  IOServiceOpen(fbService, mach_task_self(), 3, &surfacePort)`
- On success, return `IOSurfaceLookupFromMachPort(surfacePort)`

It is on the last step that `IOServiceOpen` returns error `0x2c7` (unsupported function). Notice that the 3rd argument specifying the type of connection is `3` instead of the usual `0` when opening the framebuffer service. It is almost certain that this new connection type has permissions restrictions that prevent anyone but Apple from retrieving a mach port to access the IOMFB surface.

What's somewhat interesting is that the call to `IOConnectCallScalarMethod` still works to retrieve the ID of the IOMFB surface. However, it can no longer be accessed using `IOSurfaceLookup` because the surface is no longer global. It's a little surprising that it was global in the first place!

Hope this helps demystify why IOMFB can no longer be used to record the screen.

Source: My own use of LLDB with an iPhone6 running iOS 8.4 and an iPhone6+ running iOS9 GM

Comment: I suspected that Apple somehow locked it up...is there any other way to capture an IOSurface w/o IOMobileFramebuffer, or maybe some other framework to use instead of it?

Comment: @anthonya1999 There is no way I know of to record the screen while your app is in the background. If you want to record your app, you can use the public `drawViewHierarchyInRect:` UIView method. This method is also App Store safe, though I suspect that isn't important in your case.

Comment: Very useful bit of detective work. Thanks for posting it. (Voted.) The next question is, is there an entitlement (possibly private) that Apple added so that it's apps are able to still use it? If not, what mechanism does AirPlay use to do screen mirroring? (See my question about how to do this in iOS 9 at [**Trying to do screen capture with private framework IOSurface no longer seems to work in iOS 9**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356981/trying-to-do-screen-capture-with-private-framework-iosurface-no-longer-seems-to?noredirect=1#comment53093867_32356981)

Comment: @DuncanC I think it's quite likely that there is an entitlement for this. I guess we'll know once someone has access to a jailbroken iOS9 device. AirPlay screen mirroring is a different animal though, and appears to use virtual displays. Here's what the syslog looks like when mirroring over AirPlay:

```mediaserverd[23] <Notice>:  [AirPlay] Virtual display stream activating with options <<NULL>>

mediaserverd[23] <Notice>:  [AirPlayEndpointScreen] Screen start

backboardd[57] <Notice>: IOMFB setting virtual mode: 0 0
```

Comment: Yup. The work I'm doing for my current client is pretty much stuck until we have access to an iOS 9 jailbreak so we can investigate. Jailbreaking is not an option for the final product, but private APIs ARE an option, and if we can find an entitlement it's possible that we can unlock it ourselves.

Comment: @DuncanC I'm in the same boat. I actually made iRec, which is an iOS 7-8 screen recorder, so without there being any current way to capture the screen buffer, I'm stuck myself. Trying to think of another method or some way to get around these restrictions.

Comment: @DuncanC - I think the entitlement you are looking for is `com.apple.QuartzCore.global-capture`. Can you clarify what you mean by `if we can find an entitlement it's possible that we can unlock it ourselves`? Did you had any luck solving it?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely correct - it's just a matter of an entitlement, as you can see if you dump the kext:

```
$ jtool -d __TEXT.__cstring 97.IOMobileGraphicsFamily.kext | grep com.apple
0xffffff80220c91a2: com.apple.private.allow-explicit-graphics-priority
```

If you self sign (jtool --sign --ent) with this , everything works well.

This does mean that on non-JB devices you can't use it. But with a jailbreak the immense power is in your hands once more.

Comment: Thank you, how can I sign it for the jailbreak tweak?

Answer (score 0):

IOMobileFramebuffer is completely locked down on iOS 9 and cannot be used from non-Apple apps anymore. AFAICT, this closes the last private API to capture the screen efficiently. [ReplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=605) is the only replacement, but does not allow programmatic access to the actual video data.