# Trying to do screen capture with private framework IOSurface no longer seems to work in iOS 9

Tags: screenshot, ios9, iosurface

I'm working on an existing (non app-store) app for a client that uses the IOSurface private framework to do screen captures while in the background. There are a few threads here on SO that outline the technique, as well as several open source example projects.

Again, this is an internal application used by the client. It isn't intended for app-store release, so the fact that it uses private frameworks is acceptable.

Here is an example project on Github that uses a very similar technique:

https://github.com/k06a/UIView-FastScreenshot

I just tried to run the client's app on the latest iOS 9 beta, and it crashes with the error that it is unable to load the library CoreSurface.

I've seen documentation that `CoreSurface` is the previous name of the framework that became `IOSurface`, but it also seems that in iOS 8 there is indeed a private framework called `CoreSurface` as well as a private framework called `IOSurface`.

Has anybody else been able to use `IOSurface` to do screen captures from the background in iOS 9?

I'm adding a bounty for anybody who can give me a way to make this work for iOS 9 (again, private frameworks are fine, but it can't be on a Jailbroken device)

Comment: This is actually an issue with IOMobileFramebuffer not working on ios 9. Apple actually blocked off other applications from accessing it. See the answer with 5 up votes on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239969/iomobileframebuffergetlayerdefaultsurface-not-working-on-ios-9

Comment: I'm not a twitter user. How about email? (I have a twitter account, but I can count on the fingers of 1 hand the times I've used it.)

Comment: Eek. I've got your email. I suggest you delete that post to minimize the amount of spam you get.

Comment: AFAIK, it's doable only using USB (`https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/master/tools/idevicescreenshot.c` etc.) or using AirPlay API's.